# We are not customer service for Stellar

Tags: discussion, scope

As I have already noticed questions that border on this issue I thought it best to point this out in a meta post.

As with most sites we do not operate as a customer service for Stellar, any questions or complaints about your own service/experience with them is best asked using their handy [contact us](https://www.stellar.org/contact/) button on their website as well as a large customer support base [here](https://stellarorg.zendesk.com/hc/en-us) which may be better sources of information to turn to in such situations.

This is somewhat similar to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company) meta post on Stack Overflow but to summarize a few key points.

- We're not Stellar Customer Service.
- We're not here to act as customer support on any company's behalf (including Stellar).

Hope this clears up the issue