# Are we advisers on Stellar as an investment?

Tags: discussion, scope

Should questions about the value of stellar be allowed?

An extension of [this meta post](https://stellar.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7/we-are-not-customer-service-for-stellar).

Answer (score 7):

**No.**

This Stack Exchange is for questions and discussions about Stellar as a blockchain technology and utility, not necessarily its value. (Though in my opinion questions about wallets, terminology, history, etc. are fine.)

It would lead to "Should I buy" posts and low quality spam.