# Custom Close Reasons for the Stellar Sites

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, graduation

When voting to close (or flagging to close) a question on Stellar the only options are "Off topic" and "Belongs elsewhere" - as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot of closure dialogue]

The facility exists on sites to add three site-specific close reasons.  The Stellar site has existed for long enough now that the community should be able to come up with some good reasons.  This is especially true since we are now to [graduate](https://stellar.meta.stackexchange.com/q/173/683).

There is an "Other" reason on the dialogue, where you can type a custom message for your reason to close.  However, regularly used reasons should have their own entry for simplicity and consistency.

Please add some suggestions below, and those with highest votes will be added in due course.

Answer (score 1):

I would propose:

*We are not customer service for Stellar*.

This reason was discussed on meta in the very early days of the site...
[We are not customer service for Stellar](https://stellar.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7/683)
We get a steady stream of closures for this reason. Questions that can only be answered by the Stellar Foundation, not by our community.

Indeed that link would be put into the dialogue.