# Stellar is Graduating

Tags: discussion, status-completed, graduation

You may have noticed a few Beta sites here on StackExchange have announced that they are to graduate from Beta status on 16<sup>th</sup> December.  Stellar will be one of those sites.

A formal announcement and details will appear on [The Main Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) in due course.

In the short term little will change, we will lose the "Beta" label.  The reputation required for privilege levels remains the same and we will not get a site-specific design.

Next year at some point there will be a Graduation Election to elect moderators for the graduated site.